# how to change axis sizes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a plot like this
[image]

How can I change the length of y axis to [0 20] in order to have bigger plot size.
Assume I want x axis [0 20]
y axis [0 20]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immediately after the `plot` command:

```
set(gca, 'ylim', [0 20], 'xlim', [0 20]);
```